# AJAX Tab Container style not working correctly in IE 11

Tags: css, ajax, tabcontrol

I found this link some time ago and have used the styles with the AJAX Tab Container control with changes over the years in different projects:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raghavau/css-style-sheet-for-ajax-tabcontainer-control-in-Asp-Net-2-0/

The link is just for reference but the problem I'm having is in IE 11.
It works ok in FF and Chrome.

The problem is, while viewing in IE, the left and right sides (images) of the tab have a greater height. This leaves and empty gap at the bottom of each tab where the inner portion is.

Picture three images. Left and right are 20px and the inner is 17px and all aligned at the top. And I have checked, all images have the same height.

There is also a visible dashed box around the active tab's text and the bottom of this dashed box happens to align with the bottom of the repeated inner image. Active, hover, and inactive styles are all the same except for the image.

Here is some css to view for the inactive tabs but it does the same thing on all tabs whether inactive or not.

```
/*Header*/
.Tab .ajax__tab_header {
    color: #4682b4;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 0px;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}
/*Body*/
.Tab .ajax__tab_body
{
    border:1px solid #b4cbdf;
    padding-top:0px;
    min-width:900px;
}
/*Tab Inactive*/
.Tab .ajax__tab_tab
{
    color: #666666;
    background:url("../images/tab_Inactive.gif") repeat-x;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
    line-height:20px;
}
.Tab .ajax__tab_inner
{
    color: #666666;
    background:url("../images/tab_left_inactive.gif") no-repeat left;
    padding-left:4px;
}
.Tab .ajax__tab_outer
{
    color: #666666;
    background:url("../images/tab_right_inactive.gif") no-repeat right;
    padding-right:4px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

I have been looking everywhere for a solution and even a coworker who knows styles better than I do is at a loss as to why it does not work properly in IE 11.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT**: First the dotted box around a selected tab is solved. Just needed to add `outline: 0px;`

And after closer inspection, it looks like the middle image background is not smaller, but the position is not on the bottom like it should be. Adding `background-position: bottom;` did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution and wanted to post it for others.
When I noticed the image was not smaller but it was raised, I looked closer at other elements. All that was needed for IE 11 to behave was `vertical-align: bottom;` Adding this to all the tab styles (hover, active, inactive, inner, outer, tab) did the trick.